# hide all td in a table excluding the clicked one

Tags: jquery, hide, html-table, jsfiddle, jquery-traversing

I have a fieldset in which I have a table with multiple tr and td . I have to hide all the td upon click event except the td that is clicked inside the fieldset.
I tried traversing to the parent tr of the tds that have to be clicked and then set the css to "display:none" . But it seems to hide all the td instead.

Here is my fiddle. Could this be achieved using the same the same traversals .

```
           $('#fieldset_QCNew table tbody tr td:nth-child('+index+')').css("display","none");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rawatdeepesh/dzg68ajk/1/

Comment: I don't understand ? pls say simply what you need ?

Comment: I just want to hide the unclicked boxes that are being shown in the fiddle.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
$(function() {
    $('td').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('table').find('td').not(this).toggle();
    });
});
```

**NOTE**: If you'd like the cells to maintain their positions then using `.css("visibility", "hidden")` rather than `.hide()` or `toggle` -- which use `.css("display", "none")` -- would achieve that.

```js
$(function() {
    $('td').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('table').find('td').not(this).toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col A</th>
      <th>Col B</th>
      <th>Col C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1,1</td>
      <td>1,2</td>
      <td>1,3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2,1</td>
      <td>2,2</td>
      <td>2,3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3,1</td>
      <td>3,2</td>
      <td>3,3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter.I did the same , but it only works for the firs td. I changed the traversal code to `$('#fieldset_QCNew table tbody tr').children('td').not(this).toggle()` . Here is the updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rawatdeepesh/dzg68ajk/9/

Comment: You seem to have a table within a table within a table! Would you clearly give the **structure** of your table so we don't have to go through the html in jsfiddle to find that out. Any particular reason for using such a complex structure?

Comment: This table is made in a 3rd party tool that is why its structure is so weird . I tried traversing to the parent of the target tds but the toggle is still working for the first td. Any Suggestions.
thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use

```
$(this).closest('table').find('td').not(this).toggle();
```

This should find the parent first and then locare the td inside it and perform operation on the result except the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Pls add the id="td_col" in that td's like

```
<td id="td_col" style="vertical-align:top;width:25%;">
```

And the add the below script

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#td_col', function(event) {

 $("[id^=td_col]").hide();
 $(this).show();

});
```

Refer the jsfiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/mutvairam/ymysc1sv/

Comment: Thanks for your response but i cant add id since its id is generated from the third party tool!

Comment: Ohh... Now check jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mutvairam/ymysc1sv/1/  it is okay,